# Building Commerce Engine in VSTS (Hosted VS2017) fails to restore packages

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I'm trying to build our Commerce Engine project in VSTS, but restoring packages is failing with:

> Package Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines 4.0.1 is not compatible with net462 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2) / win7-x64. Package Sitecore.Framework.Pipelines 4.0.1 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)

(The error appears for every `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` and `Sitecore.Framework.*` package that's referenced)

Answer (score 1):

The `NuGet` task doesn't support the newer Target Framework Monikor mappings required to pull this off. Use the ".NET Core" task and it will build as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Add a **NuGet Tool Installer** task before your NuGet restore task, which will force the use of the latest version of NuGet (currently 4.3.0).  I had the same issue and this resolved it.